# Displaying NUnit tests code coverage on Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nunit

I've setup a new pipeline on Azure DevOps which builds and run the tests of the projects. The tests are written with NUnit.

In the pipeline I'm using the `VSTest@2` task to run the unit tests and I add the `codeCoverageEnabled` to `true`.

In the end the pipeline runs and when I go in the "Code Coverage" tab of the job, it allows me to download `.codecoverage` file but it does not display its content in the tab. My understanding was that this should happen.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

By default, the code coverage for the VSTest Task is output to a `.codecoverage` file, which Azure DevOps does not know how to interpret and only provides as a downloadable file. You'll need to use a few `DotNetCoreCLI` tasks and [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) to be able to display code coverage results on the  code coverage tab in azure pipelines.

So, if you are on .NET CORE, There is a way how you can do that.

**Step 1** 
add `Coverlet.collector` nuget Package in your test project

**Step 2**
Change your `azure-pipelines.yml` to include the following for your code coverage:
If you have any settings from a `CodeCoverage.runsettings` file, you can keep them too

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: -c $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- RunConfiguration.DisableAppDomain=true
    testRunTitle: 'Run Test and collect Coverage' 
  displayName: 'Running tests'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
  displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool

- script: reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports -reporttypes:"Cobertura"
  displayName: Create reports

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports/Cobertura.xml
```

One other thing to note for the above code is the [Report Generator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator). Depending on which version of .net core you are using it might be required to get a different version of the tool.

More information can also be found on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I can't yet understand why but it seems that I can't build using the `dotnet` binary. But if I understand you correctly I NEED to use coverlet to be able to convert the .codecoverage file into Cobertura format for the code coverage to be displayed correctly ?

Comment: Coverlet is an important element in making this work but not the only known way. Since you can't access `dotnet`, I assume you are on .Net Framework. There are also alternatives you can try, such as [DotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) or [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) for input for the report generator, however I have no experience with those.

Comment: I just received an alert regarding this question and I realized I did not say thanks for your fully detailed answer... So thanks mate ! :D Did not get the chance to look back to this one but will certainly do.

Comment: just an fyi: I am able to use the msbuild task to build my framework projects and then call the above tasks to run my tests and get code coverage. It is not quite ideal but it does get the job done for me.